# Multicollinearity with fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

I have a dataset with N=90,000 observations, where each observation is a respondent in a survey. Respondents vary across multiple countries (50) and years (8).

Each respondent was only surveyed once, and respondents in each country were only surveyed in a given year. So, for example -- all respondents from Mexico (MEX) were surveyed in 2008, all respondents from Canada were surveyed in 2010, all respondents from the US were surveyed in 2008.

My main independent variable (X) is observed at the country level and varies between years. I want to estimate a fixed effects regression model with country and year fixed effects (SEs clustered at the country level), where my outcome of interest is observed at the individual level (support for party).

Is this the appropriate model or will this cause issues with multicollinearity (will country and year dummies soak up the variation?). If so, is there an obvious solution?

Example data:

```
respondent, country, year, independent_var, dependent_var,  age,  sex
1           MEX      2008     2               9              30    F
2           MEX      2008     2               5              18    M
3           MEX      2008     2               7              50    F
4           CAN      2008     9               3              70    M
5           CAN      2008     9               10             30    F
6           USA      2010     3               5              20    M
7           USA      2010     3               9              19    M
```

Comment: Welcome. Which variable(s) do you suspect will be absorbed by the fixed effects? Everything seems okay to me.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBilach. I specifically worry about `independent_var`. When I run the `felm()` function in R, I get the warning message `In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) : the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite` and `independent_var` shows NAs instead of an estimate. Moreover, my `independent_var` is not collinear with any of my controls (like age, sex, etc.).

Comment: @ThomasBilach, I guess another concern is that the year and country FEs are collinear with one another.

Comment: Does your main independent variable vary over time? Note how all the respondents have similar values—within a year. Why is this? Do they really all answer a survey question(s) in the same way?